# Need help adding user interface to docx4j code

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, docx4j, windowbuilder

I'm trying to create a GUI for my code but I can't figure out how to.
I'm new to coding and I'd really appreciate some help.
I don't know if I created JfileChoosers correctly and I need some help with the "Process"(btnRun) button. Pretty sure I did all of it wrong. Thanks in advance!

Original code

```
public static final String input_DOCX = "E:\\2020\\bilous.docx";

public static final String input_XML = "E:\\2020\\bilous.xml";

public static final String output_DOCX = "E:\\2020\\output.docx";

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    WordprocessingMLPackage wordMLPackage = Docx4J.load(new File(input_DOCX));
    FileInputStream xmlStream = new FileInputStream(new File(input_XML));
    Docx4J.bind(wordMLPackage, xmlStream, Docx4J.FLAG_BIND_INSERT_XML | Docx4J.FLAG_BIND_BIND_XML | Docx4J.FLAG_BIND_REMOVE_SDT);
    Docx4J.save(wordMLPackage, new File(output_DOCX), Docx4J.FLAG_NONE);
    System.out.println("Saved: " + output_DOCX);
}
```

GUI Code

```
frame = new JFrame();
frame.setBounds(100, 100, 450, 300);
frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
frame.getContentPane().setLayout(null);

txtPath = new JTextField();
txtPath.setBounds(10, 10, 414, 21);
frame.getContentPane().add(txtPath);
txtPath.setColumns(10);

JButton btnBrowse = new JButton("Browse");
btnBrowse.setBounds(10, 41, 87, 23);
frame.getContentPane().add(btnBrowse);

textField = new JTextField();
textField.setBounds(11, 73, 413, 20);
frame.getContentPane().add(textField);
textField.setColumns(10);

btnBrowserXml = new JButton("Browser Xml");
btnBrowserXml.setBounds(10, 104, 89, 23);
frame.getContentPane().add(btnBrowserXml);

btnRun = new JButton("Process");
btnRun.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
  }
});
btnRun.setBounds(170, 172, 89, 23);
frame.getContentPane().add(btnRun);}

public static final String input_DOCX = "txtPath";

public static final String input_XML = "textField";

public static final String output_DOCX = "btnRun";
private JButton btnRun;

public static void main1(String[] args) throws Exception {
    WordprocessingMLPackage wordMLPackage = Docx4J.load(new File(input_DOCX));
    FileInputStream xmlStream = new FileInputStream(new File(input_XML));
    Docx4J.bind(wordMLPackage, xmlStream, Docx4J.FLAG_BIND_INSERT_XML | Docx4J.FLAG_BIND_BIND_XML | Docx4J.FLAG_BIND_REMOVE_SDT);
    Docx4J.save(wordMLPackage, new File(output_DOCX), Docx4J.FLAG_NONE);
    System.out.println("Saved: " + output_DOCX);

// File Docx   
btnBrowse.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    JFileChooser fileChooser = new JFileChooser();

    // For File
    fileChooser.setFileSelectionMode(JFileChooser.FILES_ONLY);

    fileChooser.setAcceptAllFileFilterUsed(false);

    int rVal = fileChooser.showOpenDialog(null);
    if (rVal == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
      txtPath.setText(fileChooser.getSelectedFile().toString());
    }
  }
});

// File XML
btnBrowserXml.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
      JFileChooser fileChooser = new JFileChooser();

      // For File
      fileChooser.setFileSelectionMode(JFileChooser.FILES_ONLY);

      fileChooser.setAcceptAllFileFilterUsed(false);

      int rVal = fileChooser.showOpenDialog(null);
      if (rVal == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
          textField.setText(fileChooser.getSelectedFile().toString());
      }
    }
  });
```

Sorry for so much code, I just don't know what wouldn't be useful.

Comment: 1) *"I just don't know what wouldn't be useful."* Anything more than the minimum needed to compile / run & see the problem. For better help sooner, [edit] to add a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/). 2) Java GUIs have to work on different OS', screen size, screen resolution etc.  using different PLAFs in different locales.  As such, they are not conducive to pixel perfect layout.  Instead use layout managers, or [combinations of them](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5630271/418556) along with layout padding and borders ..

Comment: .. for [white space](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17874718/418556). 3) *"I don't know if I created JfileChoosers correctly and I need some help with the "Process"(btnRun) button."* What is your **one** question for **this** thread? It is a Q&A site, not a help desk.